Elliptic integrals in pendulum's angle as a function of time
When I was solving for angle made by the string of the pendulum with the vertical as a function of time I stumbled upon an integral of the type
$$j\int_0^x\frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos x-k}}\,\mathrm{d}x.$$
where $k$ and $j$ are constants.
Upon research I found that this is an elliptic integral, which does have a solution. But then how do you exactly compute it and why doesn't this function has an integral?

Why doesn't this function has an integral? There is no reason to expect that an integral can be expressed in terms of a finite number of elementary functions.

The denominator is actually (cos(x) - k) and j is multiplied by the integral

Although this integral arose in a physics context, the question is really more appropriate for Math SE.

Take a look at https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/653845/123208

You might find Liouville's theorem to be of interest.  The Wikipedia article is pretty terse, but here's a paper that describes it in more detail.  (It gets pretty technical, though.)

...which does have a solution. does it?
